# JTable Need Information Rows

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am building a table that needs information rows that essentially shows information of all the data below it.

```
A1 INFORMATION ROW- FIXED WHEN SCROLLING HORIZONTALLY
A2 B2 C2 D2
A3 B3 C3 D3
A4 B4 C4 D4
A5 INFORMATION ROW- FIXED WHEN SCROLLING HORIZONTALLY
A6 B6 C6 D6
A7 INFORMATION ROW- FIXED WHEN SCROLLING HORIZONTALLY
A8 B8 C8 D8
A9 B9 C9 D9
```

I would like the information rows to remain in centered full view as the user scrolls horizontally...

Not sure if the information row should be an actual row in a JTable or if there is another way I can achieve this.
Any help/advice is appreciated.

Posts: 1
Joined: Mon May 11, 2020 11:25 pm

Comment: A JTable is not a spreadsheet.  You'd have to create or find a custom Swing component to do what you're asking.

Comment: *I would like the information rows to remain in centered full view as the user scrolls horizontally* - no idea what that means. When a component is scroll the entire panel scrolls. How would expect one row of components to remain fixed.

Comment: Let me try and be clear on what I'm looking for. i essentially am looking for an information bar that appears within the table. This information bar will, for instance, display the date of all of the entries that will follow. This information bar can be a row all by itself or maybe there is another solution?  It seems as making this information bar a row can't be done.  I was thinking to possibly creating a titled border on the row which the new data will start... Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you can use a `JTreeTable`. It is like a JTree so you could have a node with the date. Then each row would contain multiple columns. There is no standard component in the JDK that does this so you will need to find 3rd party implementation. Search the forum/web for example.

Comment: I thought of that but if the user scroll right the information bar will disappear.  Is there a way I can create an empty row and get the x and y coordinates of said row and then paste a banner over the row on any scrolling or window resize?